# Masonry will specific layout

Tags: css, masonry

I suspect I just don't know how to think about this problem in order to search for an answer.

I am using masonry to lay out 17 blocks. The blocks are either 50% or 25% wide. My issue is that I want to achieve a 4 1 layout so it looks like this:

`1 1 | 
    |  1
1 1 |`

Instead, masonry is automatically running the 25% wide divs in one row like this:

`1 1 1 1
1`

Any advice on how to achieve what I want is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try this HTML

```
<div class="columns">
  <div class="column">
    1
  </div>
    <div class="column">
    1
  </div>
</div>

<div class="columns">
   <div class="column" style="margin-left: auto;display: block">
    1
  </div>
</div>

<div class="columns">
  <div class="column">
    1
  </div>
    <div class="column">
    1
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.columns{
  width: 100%;
}
.column{
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  background:red;
  margin-top: 1em;
}
```

https://codepen.io/ClarkCalnia/pen/jwBEJw

Comment: Thank you for the response. However, I am working with Masonry.js and I am looking for a solution that uses that library.